# Qt Q_Property gives a compile time error

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to Qt and C++, but a long time Delphi programmer.

I have a simple class that I am trying to add a property to:

```
class Rectangle {

    Q_PROPERTY(int width READ m_width WRITE m_width )

  public:
    void setWidth(int x) {m_width = x;}
    void setHeight(int x){m_height = x;}

    void setValues (int,int);
    int area() {return m_width * m_height;}
  private:
    int m_width, m_height;
};

void Rectangle::setValues (int x, int y) {
  m_width = x;
  m_height = y;
}
```

In main i have:

```
    Rectangle r;
    r.setWidth(7);
//    r.width = 8;
    r.setHeight(3);

    qDebug() << r.area();
```

This works fine and 21 is output (woohoo I can do 7 x 3).  But when I uncomment the line r.width = 8; I get an error which says:

" C2039: 'width' : is not a member of 'Rectangle' "

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I'm using Qt 5.4.0 and QtCreator 3.3.0

Comment: If your problem is solved, please mark one the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Inherit from `QObject`
- Include `Q_OBJECT` macro into your class body
- Use setter/getter **member functions** in the `Q_PROPERTY` READ/WRITE attribute, not the member variable.

  ```
  class Rectangle : public QObject
  {
      Q_OBJECT
      Q_PROPERTY(int width READ width WRITE setWidth)

  public:
      void setWidth ( int width )
      {
          m_width = width;
      }

      int width () const
      {
          return m_width;
      }

  private:
      int m_width;
  };
  ```
- Alternatively, you can also use the `MEMBER` keyword in the `Q_PROPERTY` ( altho personally never used it )

  ```
  class Rectangle : public QObject
  {
      Q_OBJECT
      Q_PROPERTY(int width MEMBER m_width)

  public:
      /*
      // not needed anymore if you only want to use it via the QObject property API
      void setWidth ( int width )
      {
          m_width = width;
      }

      int width () const
      {
          return m_width;
      }*/

  private:
      int m_width;
  };
  ```

Comment: Are you sure that `MEMBER` in `Q_PROPERTY` allows to access private class members?

Comment: Yes, this works. Check the first example here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html

Answer (score 1):

Please read [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) for a concise overview of QT's property system.

You'll need to add `QObject` as a base class, and change your `Q_PROPERTY` line:

```
class Rectangle : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(int width MEMBER m_width)

    // Rest of your code ...
}
```

You can then delete or make your setter functions `protected` or `private`. Alternatively, you could keep using your setter and thus prevent read access:

```
 Q_PROPERTY(int width WRITE setWidth)
```

After that, access the `m_width` value using QT functions. E.g. in `main`:

```
Rectangle r;
r.setProperty("width", 8);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Properties can be used to "surface" private member variables and can be used with setters and getters.  I use them a lot in Delphi.  Here's a page I've been looking at for help: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_Q_PROPERTY

Comment: @MichaelVincent So, does this answer your questions or is something still unclear?

Comment: No it doesn't answer the question.  I still have the error.

Comment: @MichaelVincent You have the error because it doesn't work that way. `Q_PROPERTY` does not define a member which you can access like `r.width`, but a meta member which you can access like this: `r.setProperty("width", 8);`. This may be different in Delphi, but in C++ that's the way it is. Check the link to doc.qt.io provided in the answer for a complete overview and example. EDIT: I edited the answer to better reflect that.

Comment: Ah. Gotcha. Thanks.  The compile error has gone, but I still get 21 output, sigh.

Comment: @MichaelVincent You're right, there's still something wrong with your `Q_PROPERTY` line. `Q_PROPERTY` accepts `MEMBER` with a following member variable, or `READ` and `WRITE` with following setter / getter functions. You mixed the two up. I again edited the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

start the class as this if using Q_PROPERTY

```
class Rectangle : public QObject
 {
     Q_OBJECT
...
```

Comment: Thank you, Luca.  I had tried that, and tried it again just now.  I get the same error reported.

Comment: yes , it is not enough , it should be Q_PROPERTY(int width MEMBER m_width) or Q_PROPERTY(int width READ getWidth WRITE setWidth) see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html